# Accept 2 digits after decimal while using cin

Tags: c++, input, precision

I use setprecision(2) with cout. is there a way to accept variable values with a particular floating point precision?

Comment: If the input is `12.3456.78` are you expecting that `double x, y; cin.precision(2); cin >> x >> y;` would result in x is 12.34 and y is 56.78?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by using `std::cin.precision(2);` in the previous line

Comment: I doubt that you were. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54a51bc0ac031a4c), for example.